# What is the difference between the two garage views?

Tags: gran-turismo-sport

In *Gran Turismo: Sport*, unlocked cars can go to an inner or outer menu list, but I can’t see the logic.  This video demonstrates the difference I am describing, the “inner” list is shown in the last few seconds:

What is the distinction between these two categories?  As far as I have noticed, there doesn’t seem to be crossover, a car is on one list or the other but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "outer" list is just a set of a few free cars given to new players (e.g. I don't think you can customize their livery), while the "inner" list is the cars you own either by purchasing from the brand central or by doing the daily workout.